# Parallel collapse + reduction not working

Tags: parallel-processing, nested, fortran, doparallel

I am trying to parallelize a two nested loop and the collapse clause fails.

Hey there, I am trying to parallelize these two nested loops in order to calculate two integrals (int_coulomb and int_overlap). My problem comes when I apply the collapse clause, then my code does not manage to recover the result from the in serial.

Furthermore, I added the possibility to launch the fortran program (compiled in parallel) with the selected number of processors. If I do ./program input.inp -omp 1 my code neither works.

On the other hand, when I eliminate the collapse clause, my code is slower than the serial but gives me the correct result.

```
This is my code:

!$omp parallel do private(i,j,r,dist,invdst,sf,sf0,screen_pot) &
!$omp collapse(2) & 
!$omp reduction(+:int_coulomb,int_overlap) 
!    aceptor
     do i = 1, aceptor%n_points_reduced
        do j = 1, donor%n_points_reduced

           r(1) = (aceptor%xyz(1,i)-donor%xyz(1,j))
           r(2) = (aceptor%xyz(2,i)-donor%xyz(2,j))
           r(3) = (aceptor%xyz(3,i)-donor%xyz(3,j))
!
           dist = dsqrt(DOT_PRODUCT(r,r))
!
!          Skip when grid points are coincident to avoid instabilities
           if (dist.le.1.0e-14) then
              int_coulomb = int_coulomb + zero
              int_overlap = int_overlap + zero
           else
              invdst = one/dist
!
!             Screening function 
              sf  = dist / QMscrnFact

              sf0        = erf(sf)
              screen_pot = sf0
!   
!             Integrate charges as rho_aceptor * rho_donor * (1/dist) * screening
!               --> the density has been already weigthed by the cube volume
              int_coulomb = int_coulomb +&
                            aceptor%rho_reduced(i) * donor%rho_reduced(j) * invdst * screen_pot
!   
!             Aceptor-donor overlap 
              int_overlap = int_overlap +&
                            aceptor%rho_reduced(i) * donor%rho_reduced(j)
!   
           endif      
!
        enddo
     enddo
!$omp end parallel do`
```

Any ideas?

Comment: It's very difficult to sort anything out without a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). But at the very least please tell us what do you mean by "does not manage to recover the result from the in serial." What numbers do you get? How do you know they are different to the expected accuracy of the algorithm? How many threads? Is the parallel result repeatable or not? How do you know the serial result is correct?

Comment: From what you have here it's not possible to say anything about  "I added the possibility to launch the fortran program (compiled in parallel) with the selected number of processors". Note also that should read "threads" not processors. The difference is important.

Comment: Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. I second the request written by Ian. We need more detail. When you present some code, at least al symbols should be declared. Often, a full [mre] is necessary. See also [ask].

Comment: Also, you should mention the compiler version you are using.